# #error "SSE2 instruction set not enabled" when including <emmintrin.h>

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, intel, sse2

I´m trying to compile some C++ code with cmake and make that uses the include `<emmintrin.h>` and get the following make error:

```
 #error "SSE2 instruction set not enabled"
```

I have an Intel Celeron Dual Core processor with a Linux (Mint) system (Kernel 3.5).

According to Wikipedia the Celeron Dual Core is capable to execute SSE2 instructions and the sse2 flag is set according to `/proc/cpuinfo`. But the author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894446/taking-advantage-of-sse-and-other-cpu-extensions) mentions a limited SSE support of the Intel Celeron.

I've already tried to use the SSE compiler options in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} "-msse -msse2 -msse3")
```

..but nothing changed. `cmake .` works fine but `make` gives the error message above.

Do I have to change the settings in CMakeLists.txt or does the Celeron Dual Core simply not (fully) support SSE2?

Comment: Did you check your BIOS settings? http://www.techarp.com/showfreebog.aspx?lang=0&bogno=259

Comment: Yes, my BIOS has no settings for enabling or disabling SSE.

Comment: cmake and make doesn't map one-to-one. If you are using generated makefile for make, pls make sure it has got those SSE2 flags in.

Comment: Did you try `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -msse -msse2 -msse3")` (note the position of the quotation marks) or `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -msse -msse2 -msse3")`?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -msse -msse2 -msse3")` works! Thank you! Do you have any idea why? And please post your comment as answer so I can accept it...

Comment: You are including a wrong file! See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144545/sse-instruction-set-not-enabled/23839884#23839884) in similar topic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} "-msse -msse2 -msse3")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -msse -msse2 -msse3")
```

The `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` are applied to C files, and from your post's C++ tag, I guess you're compiling C++ files, hence the need to change `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` instead.

As for the positioning of the quotation marks; in your original version, you were setting `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` to contain 2 separate entries, the first being the starting value of `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and the second being the string `"-msse -msse2 -msse3"`.

CMake holds lists like this as semi-colon separated entries.  In the case of `CMAKE_<lang>_FLAGS`, invariably they are a single value comprised of a string containing all the required flags.

Comment: This save my day. thank you so much. (try to build bwa on hadoop).

Comment: Is there a portable way to do this?? Especially in modern CMake, like target based where you're not supposed to be manipulating the global CXX flags. This seems like the wrong way to do it now days.