# #error “SSE2 instruction set not enabled” when installing scikit-bio via pip

Tags: python, gcc, pip, sse2, skbio

I want to install the python library scikit-bio via pip using following command:

```
sudo pip install scikit-bio
```

on my system:

```
uname -a
Linux grassgis 3.2.0-69-generic-pae #103-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 2 05:15:53 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

However this causes an error:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c skbio/alignment/_ssw/_ssw_wrapper.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/skbio/alignment/_ssw/_ssw_wrapper.o
    In file included from skbio/alignment/_ssw/ssw.h:17:0,
                     from skbio/alignment/_ssw/_ssw_wrapper.c:355:
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include/emmintrin.h:32:3: error: #error "SSE2 instruction set not enabled"
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1532:1: warning: ‘_import_array’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:226:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I ran already `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to get the most recent versions of installed software.

My GCC version is:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

How can I successfully install the scikit-bio packages for python?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410149/error-sse2-instruction-set-not-enabled-when-including-emmintrin-h

Comment: A couple of questions.

1. What machine are you using?  If your machine is really old, there is a chance that you machine simply doesn't have SSE2 instructions built in.

2. Exactly what Ubuntu distribution are you using?  Are you using Precise?

Answer (score 4):

This problem was previously [reported by a user](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/issues/409) with an i686 machine on the scikit-bio issue tracker. The error occurs while compiling SSW, an external C program that is shipped with scikit-bio. The author of SSW recommended passing `-msse2` to the compiler to fix the issue.

A [fix was merged](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/pull/761) into the development branch of scikit-bio to include this flag for i686 machines.

If you are installing a release version of scikit-bio, you can specify this flag via `CFLAGS` on the command line:

```
CFLAGS=-msse2 pip install scikit-bio
```

or:

```
sudo CFLAGS=-msse2 pip install scikit-bio
```

Alternatively, scikit-bio's `setup.py` file can be modified to include `'-msse2'` in SSW's `extra_compile_args`.